# Run Script on Mac prompts Error?

Tags: swift, macos, applescript

Attempting to run an apple script In Xcode Using the swift language, when i Build my project and run it i receive an error that i searched google for with no help
Here is what i have Running in my IBaction Submit button

```
let myAppleScript = "/calc.scpt"
        var error: NSDictionary?
        if let scriptObject = NSAppleScript(source: myAppleScript) {
            if let outputString = 
scriptObject.executeAndReturnError(&error).stringValue {
                print(outputString)
            } else if (error != nil) {
                print("error: ", error!)
            }
        }
```

this error message is displayed in Debug Area >

```
error:  {
    NSAppleScriptErrorBriefMessage = "A \U201c/\U201d can\U2019t go here.";
    NSAppleScriptErrorMessage = "A \U201c/\U201d can\U2019t go here.";
    NSAppleScriptErrorNumber = "-2740";
    NSAppleScriptErrorRange = "NSRange: {0, 1}";
}
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
let myAppleScript = "/calc.scpt"
if let scriptObject = NSAppleScript(source: myAppleScript) { ... }
```

creates a script object with the given source *code,* i.e. `/calc.scpt` is interpreted as AppleScript commands (and the error
message is about the initial slash character).

To create a script object from an AppleScript source *file,* use `init?(contentsOf:error:)`:

```
let scriptURL: URL = // ... URL for "calc.scpt" file 
var error: NSDictionary?
if let scriptObject = NSAppleScript(contentsOf: scriptURL, error: &error) {
    // ...
}
```